# Android custom view group delegate addView

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I want to implement custom `ViewGroup` in my case derived from `FrameLayout` but I want all child views added from xml to be added not directly into this view but in `FrameLayout` contained in this custom `ViewGroup`.
Let me show example to make it clear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout_child_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout_top"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</merge>
```

And I want to redirect adding all child view to `FrameLayout` with id `frame_layout_child_container`.

So of course I overrode methods `addView()` like this

```
  @Override
    public void addView(View child) {
        this.mFrameLayoutChildViewsContainer.addView(child);
    }
```

But for sure this doesn't work because for this time `mFrameLayoutChildViewsContainer` is not added to the root custom view.

My idea is always keep some view on on the top in this container `frame_layout_top` and all child views added into custom component should go to `frame_layout_child_container`

Example of using custom view

```
   <CustomFrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello World!"/>
    </CustomFrameLayout>
```

So in this case `TextView` should be added to the `frame_layout_child_container`

Is it possible to delegate adding all views into child `ViewGroup` like I described.

I have other ideas like using `bringToFront()` method every time view is added to keep them in correct z-axis order or for example when view is added, save it to array and than after inflating custom view add all views to this child `FrameLayout`

Suggest what to do in this case in order not to hit performance with reinflating all layout every time new view is added, if it is possible to implement in other way.

Comment: Are you sure you want to extend `FrameLayout`? The `orientation` attribute only works with `LinearLayout`.

Comment: I don't need orientation attribute at all :) so my answer is yes

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`View`s inflated from a layout - like your example `TextView` - are not added to their parent `ViewGroup` with `addView(View child)`, which is why overriding just that method didn't work for you. You want to override `addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)`, which all of the other `addView()` overloads end up calling.

In that method, check if the child being added is one of your two special `FrameLayout`s. If it is, let the `super` class handle the add. Otherwise, add the child to your container `FrameLayout`.

```
public class CustomFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

    private final FrameLayout topLayout;
    private final FrameLayout containerLayout;

    ...

    public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom, this, true);
        topLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_top);
        containerLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_child_container);
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        final int id = child.getId();
        if (id == R.id.frame_layout_top || id == R.id.frame_layout_child_container) {
            super.addView(child, index, params);
        }
        else {
            containerLayout.addView(child, index, params);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked great for me. One thing I want to add though, initially the views added to my child LinearLayout container weren't visible. When I used the hierarchy inspector in Android Device Monitor I noticed that the container LinearLayout itself wasn't in the view DOM. Long story short, it was because, like the op, I used a merge tag rather than an additional LinearLayout. When you do this, your android:orientation attribute needs to be added to the ViewGroup that it is being merged into, not the merge tag itself. My views appeared once I added this to my other parent view's layout file.

Comment: Also it may be implemented by checking `getChildCount() == 0`.