# App Crashes When Trying To Move View To Another View Group

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-relativelayout, android-custom-view

I am trying to move views defined under my custom view group into another RelativeLayout, but when I reach the code where I add the view to the new view group it crashes.

My custom view groups extends a RelativeLayout, and inflates this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/view_image_with_bottom_overlay_image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/view_image_with_bottom_overlay_overlay_container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="bottom"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="@drawable/bg_gradient_bottom_up">
  </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ImageWithBottomOverlayView :

```
public class ImageWithBottomOverlayView extends FrameLayout {

  public static final int NON_EXISTING_RESOURCE = -1;

  private ImageView imageView;
  private RelativeLayout statusContainer;

  public ImageWithBottomOverlayView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.init(context);
  }

  public ImageWithBottomOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.init(context);
    this.processAttrs(context, attrs);
  }

  public ImageWithBottomOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.init(context);
    this.processAttrs(context, attrs);
  }

  @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public ImageWithBottomOverlayView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    this.init(context);
    this.processAttrs(context, attrs);
  }

  private void init(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_image_with_bottom_overlay, this, true);

    this.imageView = (ImageView) rootview.findViewById(R.id.view_image_with_bottom_overlay_image);
    this.statusContainer =
        (RelativeLayout) rootview.findViewById(R.id.view_image_with_bottom_overlay_overlay_container);

    this.moveChildrenToStatusContainer()
  }

  private void moveChildrenToStatusContainer() {
    int childCount = this.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
      View child = this.getChildAt(i);
      this.removeView(child);

      ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = child.getLayoutParams();
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(layoutParams);
      child.setLayoutParams(newLayoutParams);

      this.statusContainer.addView(child);// it fails when this is called
    }
  }

  private void processAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ImageWithBottomOverlayView, 0, 0);
    int resourceId = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.ImageWithBottomOverlayView_imageSource, NON_EXISTING_RESOURCE);
    boolean isOverlayAlignStart = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.ImageWithBottomOverlayView_overlay_align_start, true);
    a.recycle();

    setImage(resourceId);
    setBottomOverlayGravity(isOverlayAlignStart);
  }

  private void setBottomOverlayGravity(Boolean isOverlayAlignLeft) {

    int gravity = this.statusContainer.getGravity();

    if (isOverlayAlignLeft) {
      gravity |= Gravity.START;
    } else {
      gravity |= Gravity.END;
    }

    this.statusContainer.setGravity(gravity);
  }

  public void setImage(int resId) {
    if (resId != NON_EXISTING_RESOURCE) {
      imageView.setImageResource(resId);
    }
  }

  public ImageView getImageView() {
    return this.imageView;
  }
}
```

status container is the inner RelativeLayout `view_image_with_bottom_overlay_overlay_container`

`init()` and `moveChildrenToStatusContainer()` are the major parts of ImageWithBottomOverlayView and init is called in all of the constructors.

When I get to the `addView()` part it crashes with

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.acme.ImageWithBottomOverlayView
```

below is my intended usage:

```
<com.acme.ImageWithBottomOverlayView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/task_scan_attach_image_location_status"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/ic_location_on_white_18dp"/>

</com.acme.ImageWithBottomOverlayView>
```

Comment: How are you inflating that layout into your custom `View`? When are you adding it? You'll need to provide more of the `ImageWithBottomOverlayView` class. What's the root cause of the `InflateException`? It'll be further down in the stack trace.

Comment: Please edit the question and add the custom view(ImageWithBootomOverlayView) code.

Comment: moving view shouldn't raise any error, i suppose the error is because of there is a code on `com.acme.ImageWithBottomOverlayView` that make the inflate process failed

Comment: there's no Caused By: in the stack trace. But I can see the line of code where I tried to inflate the layout where I used my custom view.

Comment: Where should I put call moveChildrenToStatusContainer() i'm realizing that the constructor is not the best place to do that.

Comment: as Shadow Droid's suggestion, please post your `com.acme.ImageWithBottomOverlayView` code

Comment: Move view directly on constructor will not raise any error

Comment: If you're calling `init()` from the constructor, then your problem is that `getChildAt(0)` is going to be the root `RelativeLayout` of the layout your inflating and attaching at the top of `init()`. Either delay attaching that inflated layout, or override `addView(View, int, LayoutParams)` to make sure everything's added where it should be, like is shown in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36947869).

Comment: overriding addView(View, int, LayoutParams) solved it! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. I'll just close your question as a duplicate of that one, then. Glad it worked for ya. Cheers!