# How to load views in XML into a child ViewGroup of the parent ViewGroup

Tags: android, viewgroup

I am trying to create a custom `ViewGroup` by extending the parent `LinearLayout` as explained in the picture. But I don't know how, when and where to add the views in the XML into the first child `LinearLayout` in the extended class of the parent `LinearLayout`?

[image: click to view the picture]

Comment: Design expected? or what exactly you want ?

Comment: If I correctly understand what you're trying to do, I've an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36947869.

Comment: Thanks, man, You give exactly what I want .